# Apple M1 and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arguments, apple-m1

python = 3.9
Apple M1

in helperfunc.py is:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

in my Jupiter-notebook is:

```
from helperfunc import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)

    results = pool.map(add, zip([1, 2, 3], repeat(10)))
```

I have tried to put the arguments in lists instead a list of tuples --> didn't work.

It gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pdf/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pdf/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [40], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      3     pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
----> 5     results = pool.map(helpfunc.add, args)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pdf/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:364, in Pool.map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    359 def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
    360     '''
    361     Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    362     in a list that is returned.
    363     '''
--> 364     return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pdf/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:771, in ApplyResult.get(self, timeout)
    769     return self._value
    770 else:
--> 771     raise self._value

TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: `Pool.map` only gives a single argument (the entire tuple containing x and y). You need to either manually unpack the arguments inside your `add` function, or use `Pool.starmap` which unpacks the arguments for you.